# UDP Search Smart Light Strip

Tags: network-programming, udp

I am trying to understand a manual of a smart light strip, because I want to control my light strip from my PC. And at page 5 cap. '3.1 Search request and response' I don't understand where I should type that searching message. Thanks.

Manual : https://www.yeelight.com/download/Yeelight_Inter-Operation_Spec.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Just as described in the manual, you should write the content of the search message into a UDP datagram and send that to the multicast address 239.255.255.250:1982

Comment: How can i build a UDP datagram? I tried google and i couldn't find anything.